# Use Models with a moving/different Sqlite databases?

Tags: django, django-models

I am looking to have a django app that visually displays a SQLite database. The idea is that the user would pass in the path to the sqlite file in the URL for the app. I was wondering if I could make use of the Django models and use something like django-tables2 to display it. I was just wondering if the Models are not setup in models.py prior to the start of the server.

Is there a way to still use Model, read/write to the given database and be able to still build the table?

Comment: What's the advantage you gain by using separate databases, especially SQLite, versus making a multi-tenant application using Postgres?

Comment: The SQLite files will be generated by a separate application. I am looking to make a django app that will easily display the contents of those files + some other features.

Comment: Gotcha. You can always modify settings at runtime using middleware, so you could set the db path that way. Your models won't care either way.